# What does it mean for a reference to be passed by value?

Tags: java

I read [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) that Java is **always pass-by-value**. And so even references are passed by value.

I don't understand what this means, can somebody clarify this for me please?

Comment: Try to follow the accepted answer in that question **line by line** until you get it, it will become clear after some attempts. Also read the definition of *reference*, it must be clear in order to understand.

Comment: A primitive type variable holds a raw value.  An object variable holds a "memory address" that points to the object.  So when you pass either of these around, it's those values which are transferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this

```
Object ref = new Object();
```

`ref` is actually storing a value, some address to an object. Let's say `1234`.

When you pass `ref` around

```
public void method(Object passed) {...}
...
method(ref);
```

Java actually copies the value of the reference and assigns it to the parameter. So, `passed` will also have the value `1234`.

Similarly, if you had

```
Object otherRef = ref;
```

the value `1234` would be copied and assigned to `otherRef`.

If you then re-assign `otherRef`, like

```
otherRef = new Object();
```

that would assign a new value to `otherRef`, but `ref` would still have the same value as before. That's what pass by value is.

When you call a method

```
ref.toString();
```

Java uses the value of the reference to find the referenced object and invoke the method. This is called dereferencing.

---

You might want to go through the JPDA javadoc, starting with [`StackFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/StackFrame.html). Go through the fields and types and you'll start to understand how everything is mapped. For example, it has a [`getValues(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/StackFrame.html#getValues%28java.util.List%29) method which returns a `Map<LocalVariable, Value>`. That should tell you that a variable doesn't actually store anything. Instead, it is mapped to a value, where that value may be [all sorts of things](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/Value.html).

Comment: Probably unrelated but your *all sorts of things* link interested me: is **null** neither a primitive nor a reference type?

Comment: @Clay Well, this isn't exactly representative. In JPDA, there is no `Value` for `null`. `null` is the value. That might be more confusing. Think of `null` as a reference value to a special location meaning nothing, say address `0`.

Comment: @Clay `null` is explained in the JLS, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7). It has the `null` type.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = 5;

public void foo(int num) {
num = num + 5;
System.out.println(num);
}

foo(a);

System.out.println(a);
```

In the above code, a is passed into foo() by value.  That means that a new variable is created with the scope of foo() that has the same initial value as a.  When the value of num is changed, the value of a is not changed.  The first println() will print a 10, the second will print a 5.  In c++ you could pass a in by reference, which means that the value of a would be changed too.

Comment: Your code isn't really compilable Java.  You might get a few upvotes if you clean that up. :)

Comment: Thanks, I haven't written Java in a while.  Been learning c++!

Comment: The OP's actually asking about passing a reference by value. In your example, `a` is an int and not a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I can try, in some other languages you have the option of passing something by a pointer (e.g. a reference to a memory region). Java calls every function with a value (not a pointer), but the value of an Object is a reference to a memory region. See also the default `toString()` in your own classes.

Answer (score 0):

I always find this a good example:

```
Dog foo = new Dog("Rocky");
modifyDog(foo);
System.out.println(foo.name); //Alice

public void modifyDog(Dog aDog)
{
   aDog.name = "Alice"; //here you change the field 'name' of the object located in memory currently referenced by foo and aDog variables. 
   aDog =  new Dog();   //since aDog is a copy of foo then this won't recreate foo object
}
```